# Error on table creation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, create-table

```
CREATE TABLE posEmployees
(
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
LName varchar(55) NOT NULL,
FName varchar(55),
Dept varchar(20),
HourlyPay numeric(10, 2),
WeeklyHours numeric(5, 2),
IsManager bit, 
Salary numeric(9,2), 
HireFire bit
)

select * from POS_EMPLOYEES

 insert into POS_EMPLOYEES (LName, FName, Dept, HourlyPay, WeeklyHours)
values ('Pride', 'Kitty', 'Sales', 5.5, 20.0)
```

No matter which way I do it, (numeric or decimal) or if I fill all fields in or not, I get this error:

> **Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.**

Comment: You have different table names in CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO

Comment: Do you have a table/view named POS_EMPLOYEES?

Comment: I tried your Code with Same Name is SELECT and INSERT Statements and it worked fine maybe you just got the names wrong :) i.e posEmployees NOT POS_EMPLOYEES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table name is different to the insert and select queries, i'm confused why you are doing a select statement too but try this:

```
CREATE TABLE posEmployees
(
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
LName varchar(55) NOT NULL,
FName varchar(55),
Dept varchar(20),
HourlyPay numeric(10, 2),
WeeklyHours numeric(5, 2),
IsManager bit, 
Salary numeric(9,2), 
HireFire bit
)

 insert into posEmployees(LName, FName, Dept, HourlyPay, WeeklyHours)
values ('Pride', 'Kitty', 'Sales', 5.5, 20.0)
```

Comment: I think it is a type problem. We all know this can solve problem .

Comment: I had changed the name and forgotten to change it both places. I was super tired working on that. Thank you.